# AES and RSA: Avoid reprocessing one request?

Tags: php, security, encryption, server, rsa

I'm trying to send data between client and server securely. I encrypt sensitive data with AES, then the encryption key with RSA, and then use signatures to make sure data is not changed.

It looks secure, but I heard about a bug, I don't know its name but that's how it works:

1. first, the client sends an encrypted request to the server.
2. hacker can see the encrypted request but cannot decrypt it.
3. hacker resends the encrypted request to the server again and again and tries to find out what's happening.

for instance, the client sends a request to the server that uploads a picture and adds that pic to his or her wall. a hacker can resend this request for hundreds of times, so the server will upload that image and adds it to the client's wall again and again. what a mess!

so my questions are:

1. what's the name of this bug? :D
2. how to stop it? it there a way to tell the server (in php for example?) to process every request only once? or there's another solution for this problem.

thanks for reading.

Comment: This is not a programming question. The real bug here is not using TLS/SSL.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I use SSL, people and companies I work for (as a freelancer) don't!   so I make sure that my apps are secure even when I have to send data over HTTP.

Comment: No offense, but there is simply no possibility you can make a secure transport layer to compete with TLS if you have to ask such a basic question. And there is no reason not to use TLS.

Comment: 1. Its called a replay attack.. 2. implement nonce tokens..

Comment: If the companies you want to send data to don't use TLS and you want to implement this as a solution, then you need access to the server-side anyway. So... If you have server-side access, why don't you just implement TLS? There is really no reason here to not, you're making excuses to use a clanky homebrew transport security implementation.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to avoid (1st question) is a replay attack against the backend, the attacker in this case can perform a [Cyphertext Only Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext-only_attack).

There is also another issue: in a protocol (like the one you are designing) the set of request/responses that can be made may be limited, and what is worse it can be guessed (think erros). This leads to an attacker being able to perform a [Known Plaintext Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack)

To overcome it (2nd question):

- use TLS (a.k.a. https) for your transport this will protect you from snooping intruders.
- Implement nonce-s that will prevent same plaintext messages having the same cyphertext, but be aware that it doesn't come even close to TLS. (As suggested by Laurence Cherone and Luke Joshua Park in the comments)

You can address follow up questions at [Security Stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com) it is dedicated to Information Security topics like these.

Comment: Your second bullet point makes no sense. Why is a symmetric algorithm not necessary? You're not suggesting the OP use RSA as a block cipher?  Additionally, this isn't a brute force attack, only a Replay attack.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice! 
You are right: nothing about the key will be revealed, it is just a replay attack. I also thought about your comment on the second bullet, but I can't find any reason why not to use RSA as a block cipher, from what I understand from crypto: cryptanalysis of symmetric key encryption is easier than that of asymmetric key encryption

Comment: Granted, what the OP wants to do is not very orthodox

Comment: One of the main issues is speed.  RSA operations are an order of magnitude slower than most symmetric operations.  Decryption is even worse.  There are also other more subtle issues that arise.  Using a symmetric algorithm is just generally better.

Comment: Agreed. I am reflecting your suggestions and mention two attacks that the communication is vulnerable to. Thanks!